# Rename View in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rename, sql-view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rename Oracle Table or View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835387/rename-oracle-table-or-view)

I know you can use

```
ALTER TABLE oldName RENAME TO newName;
```

to rename a table, but "ALTER" doesn't work with renaming views.

What's the syntax for renaming Views in Oracle (i'm using 11g if that makes any difference)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [RENAME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9019.htm) on views, like this:

> Use the RENAME statement to rename a table, view, sequence, or private synonym.

```
RENAME old_view_name to new_view_name
```