# Rename Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, alter-table, table-rename

What is the difference between ALTER TABLE RENAME statement and RENAME TABLE statement.

ie, between

```
Alter table old_table_name rename to new_table_name
```

and

```
rename table old_table_name to new_table_name.
```

Comment: This might be the answer to your question:


 http://stackoverflow.com/a/835782/1145053

Comment: Simple `rename` will only work in the same schema where the object exists, while `alter` will work from other schema too. Of course, if you have the required privileges to do so. See my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename Oracle Table or View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835387/rename-oracle-table-or-view)

Answer (score 13):

> rename table old_table_name to new_table_name.

That syntax is wrong. there is no `table` keyword required. The correct syntax is -

`rename old_table_name to new_table_name;`

Now, let's see where the difference is between `alter` statement and simple `rename` statement.

I have two schemas, `SCOTT` and `LALIT`.

```
SQL> SHOW USER
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL>
SQL> create table t(id number);

Table created.

SQL> rename t to t_new;

Table renamed.

SQL> alter table t_new rename to t_newer;

Table altered.
```

So, both the statements works in the same `schema`.

Let's connect to the other schema -

```
SQL> SHOW USER
USER is "LALIT"
SQL>
SQL> create table t(id number);

Table created.

SQL> rename scott.t_newer to t_newest;
rename scott.t_newer to t_newest
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01765: specifying owner's name of the table is not allowed


SQL> alter table scott.t_newer rename to t_newest;

Table altered.
```

So, you see the error `ORA-01765: specifying owner's name of the table is not allowed`. That's where simple `rename` statement fails on other schema objects. Only `ALTER` statement works.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it answered if you got your solution.