# Rename Oracle Table in Other Schema

Tags: oracle, rename, alter

How to rename the table which is under other schema? For example, my user is `A`, I want to rename `table_1` to `table_1_temp` which both supposed to be under the same schema, let's say schema `B`. Is that possible?

I tried this:

```sql
RENAME B.table_1 TO B.table_1_temp
```

and

```sql
RENAME B.table_1 TO table_1_temp
```

but got this error:

```
ORA-01765: specifying owner's name of the table is not allowed
```

`ALTER` statement is also doesn't work:

```sql
ALTER TABLE B.table_1 RENAME TO table_1_temp
```

got this error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

and this

```sql
ALTER TABLE B.table_1 RENAME TO B.table_1_temp
```

```
ORA-14047 ALTER TABLE|INDEX RENAME may not be combined with other operations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Insufficient privilege" is the keyword here. You can't modify other users' objects unless you're allowed to; of course you can't - how would it look like if anyone messes up with your schema?

Owner itself can't grant that privilege; it is a *strong* one and user - who is granted such a privilege - must be *trustworthy* as it can alter any other user's tables.

Have a look at the following example. There are two users in my database: `mike` (who owns a table) and `scott` (who should rename `mike`'s table).

Mike and his table:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "MIKE"
SQL> select * from tab;

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
BEDIENSTETER                   TABLE
```

Connect as `scott` and try to rename `mike`'s table (`rename` won't work here; it is supposed to be used in your own schema):

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> alter table mike.bediensteter rename to test;
alter table mike.bediensteter rename to test
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Right; insufficient privileges. What privilege is it? `ALTER ANY TABLE`. So let's grant it, connected as a privileged user (such as `SYS` in my XE database):

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant alter any table to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

OK; back to `scott`, repeat the action:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> alter table mike.bediensteter rename to test;

Table altered.
```

Succeeded! Let's see what we've done:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> select * from tab;

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
TEST                           TABLE

SQL>
```

Right; table is now renamed.

Answer (score 0):

[Rename Oracle Table or View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835387/rename-oracle-table-or-view)
as you can see on this post based on Pop's answer, the RENAME statement only works for table in the same schema.

The `ALTER TABLE B.table_1 RENAME TO table_1_temp` looks to be the best solution, have you tried giving your user account more privileges ?

Comment: yes, that looks to be the best solution but I'm just wondering whether it will be renamed to `A` schema or to `B` schema, because the schema name is not specified there. I haven't tried giving more privileges yet, need to ask DBA first.